# VK API как получить второе сообщение

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, long-poll

Я написал вот такой код. Создал основной цикл для поиска новых сообщений, если пользователь в беседе напишет /start, то запустится второй цикл, который принимает сообщение, проверяет на существование id беседы в БД, после чего второй цикл останавливается.

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.from_chat:
            id = event.chat_id
            msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()
            
            try:
                dey = event.message.action['type']
                invite_id = event.message.action['member_id']
            except:
                dey = ''
                invite_id = -100
            
            if dey == 'chat_invite_user':
                sender(id, f'Приветствую тебя, @id{invite_id}!')
            
            if msg == 'привет':
                sender(id, 'Приветствую!')
            elif msg == 'расписание':
                file = open('site.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
                file.write((requests.get('https://academicol.ru/students/schedule')).text)
                file.close()
                file = open('site.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
                sender(id, f'&#128347;Завтра в {file.read()}')
            elif msg == '/debug':
                sender(id, f'Отладочная информация: {db.get_chats(id)}')
            elif msg == '/start':
                sender(id, 'Введите вашу группу в формате ЧXXX-Ч: ')
                if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                        if(not db.chat_exists(id)):
                            # если беседы нет в базе, добавляем его
                            msgGroup = event.object.message['text'].lower()
                            db.add_chat(id, msgGroup)           
                            sender(id, 'Ваша группа будет занесена в базу данных')
                            break
                        else:
                            sender(id, 'Ваша группа уже добавлена в базу данных')
                            break
```

Но в итоге я получил это:

```
Я
/start

Бот
Введите вашу группу в формате ЧXXX-Ч:

Я
2ПСО-9 #бот это сообщение не читает

Я
/start
 
Бот
Введите вашу группу в формате ЧXXX-Ч:
Ваша группа будет занесена в базу данных
```

В итоге заносит в БД не "2ИСП-9", а команду "/start"

Как сделать "первончальную настроку" для бота?

Comment: Да, тоже с этим сталкивался. В итоге остановился на создании программы, которая будет работать со всеми индивидуально. У меня на таком способе многое висит, занимает только одну новую консоль, или же вообще можно использовать прямо в main'е с помощью subropecc.Popen().
Написать Вам код?

Comment: @Komedik да, будьте добры, напишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем, как начать, создайте в папке с главным файлом - "example.py" (Образец кода). Можно дать любое название, а лучше указывать для чего образец, например: "addChat_example.py"

```
### Главный файл ###

import shutil
import time
import os

def programmCall(file): # Функция для вызова программ, не открывая дополнительную cmd
    import subprocess
    subprocess.Popen('python', file, 'argzzz1', 'argzzz2')

if msg == '/start':
    # Советую здесь написать код, чтобы главный файл не реагировал на сообщения,
    # Пока пользователь использует индивидуальную функцию, например, занести его в игнор лист
    file = f'addChat_{id}.py' # Файл индивидуальной работы
    shutil.copyfile('addChat_example.py', file) # Копируем образец и переносим в файл индивид. работы
    with open('now id', 'w') as f: # Создаём файл, в котором передадим id
        f.write(str(id)) 
    programmCall(file) # Запускаем файл индивид. работы
    time.sleep(0.5) # Ожидание, чтобы успело получить id
    os.remove('now id') # Удаляем файл передачи id, так как он больше не нужен, а если его не удалить, то возможно, будет ошибка
    sender(id, 'Введите вашу группу в формате ЧXXX-Ч:')
```

Теперь перейдём к коду файла индивид. работы

```
### Файл индивидуальной работы ###

with open('now id', 'r') as f:
    id = int(f.read())
meFile = 'addChat_{str(id)}' # Название файла индивид. работы

# Здесь такой же импорт модулей и установка бота


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            if event.from_chat:
                new_id = event.user_id # Получаем новый id
                if new_id == id: # Если нам написал тот же пользователь
                    
                    # Здесь уже код. Теперь каждый раз, когда Вам в этом коде нужно будет ожидать сообщение - выполняйте for event in longpoll.listen() каждый раз, а при завершении поиска ответа оттуда, пишите - break

                    msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()

                    if (not db.chat_exists(id)):
                        # если беседы нет в базе, добавляем его
                        msgGroup = event.object.message['text'].lower()
                        db.add_chat(id, msgGroup)           
                        sender(id, 'Ваша группа будет занесена в базу данных')
                        # Уберите пользователя из игнор листа
                        os.remove(meFile) # Удалить себя. break всё равно придётся написать, так как если запущен цикл, код не перестаёт работать, пока не прекратиться цикл, даже если файл с кодом удалён
                        break
                    else:
                        sender(id, 'Ваша группа уже добавлена в базу данных')
                        # Уберите пользователя из игнор листа
                        os.remove(meFile)
                        break
```